# Displaying user role in a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view within my main _Layout.cshtml. The partial view is used to display info about the logged in user.

The username can be displayed using @Context.User.Identity.Name

but I also want to display the role of the user.

What would be the best way to display this info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through all of the user's roles in the View and display them accordingly:

```
@foreach(string role in Roles.GetRolesForUser(Context.User.Identity.Name))
{
    @Html.Label(role);
}
```

This utilizes the [`Roles.GetRolesForUser()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h930x07.aspx), and returns a `string[]` for all the roles (each represented as a `string`) the user is a part of.